# BeautifulSoup and line breaks within a table row?

Tags: python, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

Sample code:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer

html='''<tr>
<td align="left">Foo<br />
Bar<br /></td>
</tr>'''

soup=BeautifulSoup(html)
rows=soup.findAll('tr')
print rows
print rows[0].text.encode("utf8")
```

I would like the output to be something like "Foo Bar" or even if there was an actual newline between the two lines that would be fine, but the output I get just has "FooBar", note that there is no whitespace between the two lines.

Very new to python and beautifulsoup, can someone give a hand?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can go one level further using `cell = rows[0].find('td')`, then see its contents using `cell.contents`, then filter the elements you need, then `join` them by spaces.

Another option: you can use a regular expression for replacing the `<br />` by a space. for that you can write:

```
import re
s = re.sub('<br\s*?>', ' ', rows[0].text)
```

Then you can replace multiple consecutive whitespaces by

```
s = re.sub('\s+', ' ', s)
```

Then the string should look like this:

```
>>> print s
<tr> <td align="left">Foo Bar </td> </tr>
```

Then you can easily extract the part you need.

Comment: For now I've gone with: `print ' '.join(str(a) for a in rows[0].find('td').contents)` and am just stripping out the `<br />` tags, but I'm hoping someone can give a solution that is a little more clean. Seems like this is a flaw in beautifulsoup or I am missing something.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to consider using [lxml](http://codespeak.net/lxml/) instead of BeautifulSoup. `lxml` enables you to search for elements using [XPath](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) which (I think) is easier than using BeautifulSoup's API.

```
import lxml.html as LH

html='''<tr>
<td align="left">Foo<br />
Bar<br /></td>
</tr>'''

doc = LH.fromstring(html)
for tr in doc.xpath('//tr'):
    print(repr(tr.text_content()))
```

yields

```
'Foo\nBar\n'
```

and

```
for text in doc.xpath('//tr/*/text()'):
    print(repr(text))
```

yields

```
'Foo'
'\nBar'
```